# Data Ingress to S3 from an FTP Server

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, ingress

I have about 1.5TB of data on an FTP server from my web hosting provider that I want to migrate into S3.
From what I have read there are a number of ways to do this, including FileZilla Pro which provides support for S3.

If any of you have done this before, are there best practices that I should be aware of?
Is it possible to do this from within the AWS CLI?

I want to be able to transfer them directly without downloading them to my local machine as I don't have enough space to save all these files.
I also want to confirm that all files have been transferred properly.

Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps rsync to a mount point of fuse s3fs if the ftp server is unx